# connect bluetooth handsfree to smartphone (android) and laptop (Ubuntu) at the same time

Tags: ubuntu, android, bluetooth

when I connect my Bluetooth hands-free to the Android smartphone, I must disconnect it from my ubuntu laptop and vice versa. That is, it does not work on both devices simultaneously

Is there any way for my bluetooth handsfree to work simultaneously on both devices (ubuntu laptop + android smarthphone at the same time)?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/q/836966/776268

Comment: That is exactly what I do. However this is not what I am asking

Comment: It's still related.  However it seems like what you want to do is not possible.

Comment: @Jesse_b You may be right, however I ask if there is suddenly someone who pulls a rabbit out of the hat. Thank you

Comment: Depends if the device will allow it. Check your device's manual.